# How to design/create rules table with criteria in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

I don't have much experience with SQL Server and I'm pretty much lost when it comes to anything more advanced than simple `INSERT/SELECT` statements.

My task is to create table which hold 'criteria' (rules) for other tables in same DB. I mean we have an `Employee` table, a `Salary` table etc. I need to make some rules between `Employee` table and `Salary` table by its values, i.e. if `Employee = John` and `Salary = 2000` then make 1 criteria, if `Employee = Steve` and `Salary = 3000` then make 2 criteria.

I have created a table called `Rules`:

```
RuleID    Criteria
--------------------------------------------------    
1         Employee = John and Salary = 2000
2         Employee = Steve and Salary = 3000**
```

**My question**: As mentioned above is correct way to create 'criteria' table? (maybe I have 50 different conditions...Would it be correct way If I create table with all conditioned as mentioned above?) Please advise.

I am sorry If I am not able to explain it in correct way or asking basic question.

I would appreciate any help in this. Thanks a lot in advance..

Comment: The key to designing any set of tables is understanding how they will be used.  How are the rules being used?  Are they for SQL statements?  Just to show to users?  Code in another language?

Comment: @GordonLinoff These are for SQL statements and  later will be used in VB.Net. when form populates(run time) criteria should execute as user pick any selection(i.e. if user select Employee name = john and select Salary = 2000 then by it self ruleID 1 will execute). Apologies If I am not able to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

We have created an effective Rules Engine that notifies the appropriate user(s) for a given rule. Our columns are as follows: RuleID, RuleName, SequenceNum, IsActiveFlag, RuleRunDays, DataSteward, CarbonCopyRecipients, NotificationLevel, RuleSQL, NotificationSubject, NotificationText, HTMLFlag

The key is to have a column that is a valid executable SQL statement (as RuleSQL above). Here is an example of a value you might put in the RuleSQL column:

SELECT ErrorMessage = 'Salary cannot be null for Active employees.'
         , e.EmployeeName , es.Salary , ...
        FROM EmployeeSalary es
        JOIN Employee e
            ON e.EmployeeId = es.EmployeeId
        WHERE es.Salary IS NULL AND e.Status = 'Active'